# K8S Failed to pull image from local repo

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an image in my docker repository. I an trying to create POD out of it but K8S is giving the following error.

*Failed to pull image "cloudanswer:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)*

It seems K8S is connecting to https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ instead of taking from local docker repository.

How to make K8S take image for local docker repository ?

Comment: what do you mean local docker repository? if you have a private registry you need to specify the full image name (with registry)

Comment: Are you able to run docker login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imagePullPolicy should be set to IfNotPresent to pull images from local docker repo

Answer (score 1):

If you use **single node** in your cluster, make sure this docker image is available on this node.
You can check via

```
docker image ls
```

Also set the `imagePullPolicy` to `Never`, otherwise Kubernetes will try to download the image.

**Multiple node cluster**, you can use docker [registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry).
Use a local registry:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Now tag your image properly:

```
docker tag ubuntu <dns-name-of-machine>:5000/ubuntu
```

**dns name** of the machine running registry container should be reachable by all nodes in network

Now push your image to local registry:

```
docker push <dns-name-of-machine>:5000/ubuntu
```

You should be able to pull it back:

```
docker pull <dns-name-of-machine>:5000/ubuntu
```

Now change your yaml file to use local registry.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes supports a special type of secret that you can create that will be used to fetch images for your pods. [More details here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod)